# Custom ImageView With a Custom Shape

Tags: android, view, imageview

I am trying to create a custom ImageView that Shows images inside a custom border and shape instead of default rectangle, and out Side of The Borders are **TransParent**.

my border is an **SVG** File, How I can do this? thanks

[image: Photo examples]

Comment: see the sources of [RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://github.com/android-ia/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/donut/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.java) and create similar custom `Drawable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this library [siyamed/android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) or create a **custom view** that **extend** from View class and **override** methods!

But the easiest way is using this library

create a bitmap that you want to mask your original picture and use this like below :

```
 <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.mask.PorterShapeImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                app:siShape="@drawable/octogon" <!--mask bitmap-->
                android:src="@drawable/neo" <!-- original bitmap -->
app:siSquare="true"/>
```

[image: screenShot]

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Image View class and change it according to your use. Not just Image View you can customized any view class you just need to extend parent class.